# Apache Camel and Xpath

Tags: apache-camel

I am having trouble with xpath expressions in Apache Camel:

```
  Object obj =  exchange.getIn().getBody(Document.class);
  String tag = XPathBuilder.xpath("name(//*)").resultType(String.class).evaluate(exchange.getContext(),obj,String.class);
```

but on exit, I get the following error:

> org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.w3c.dom.Document with value [Body is instance of java.io.InputStream] due org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your body is of type stream. Convert the body to String either in the dsl via convertBodyTo(String.class) or before the xpath evalutation above.